# How to inherit & yield custom attribute from spider middleware into parse function?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to create a `job_name` inside `spider_opened(...)` in my spider middleware and use it:

1. as one of the yield values inside the parse function to write into my `scrapy_results` table
2. when logging scrapy stats in my `scrapy_log` table

I have achieved #2 using:

`middlewares.py`

```
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    spider.logger.info('************Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
    ...
    self.job_timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    self.job_name = spider.name + '_' + str(self.job_timestamp)


def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
    spider.logger.info('************Spider closed: %s, Job: %s, Reason: %s' % (spider.name, self.job_name, str(reason)))
    ...
    insert_log_statement = "insert into scrapy_logs \
            values('%s', %s, '%s', %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) " \
                % (self.job_name, self.job_timestamp, reason, downloader_request_count, response_received_count, \
                    elapsed_time_seconds, item_scraped_count, item_dropped_count)
    try:
        self.cur.execute(insert_log_statement)
    except:
        print("ERROR!! Could not commit transaction to insert log: ", insert_log_statement)

    self.connection.commit()
    self.cur.close()
    self.connection.close()
```

But for #1, I want to yield the `job_name` along with scraped fields inside the parse functions like this:

`myspider.py`

```
class AmazonbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    # job_name = spider.job_name

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield {
               'text': text,
               # 'job_name': self.job_name,
               ... }
```

How do I access the `myscraper.middlewares.MySpiderMiddleware.job_name` field inside the `MySpider` class?

Answer (score 1):

```
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    spider.logger.info('************Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
    ...
    self.job_timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    self.job_name = spider.name + '_' + str(self.job_timestamp)
```

This is the method in your middleware, you have to remember that the middleware is a class of it's own, not part of your spider, so `self.job_name` is assigning the value to the middleware (`self`), not to the spider.

Since the `spider` argument that method receives is the instance of the spider you could assign it directly like:

```
spider.job_name = spider.name + '_' + str(self.job_timestamp)
```

It would work, however I find it quite disturbing... My suggestion would be to assign this value in the spider itself, you can do it in the `__init__` method **OR** using [signals](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html) like this:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy import Spider

class AmazonbotSpider(Spider):
    ...
    
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(AmazonbotSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.logger.info('************Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
        ...
        self.job_timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
        self.job_name = spider.name + '_' + str(self.job_timestamp)
```